# Wordpress Multiple Loop

Tags: themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Which is the best solution when we have multiple loops in the same page? I am using for the main loop this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Now i am trying to add a new loop in the same page (in a different location) for featured posts in a specific category name, which is for you the best choice: ("content" is just for example)

1- Use get_posts();

```
<?php global $post;
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'destaques' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

   "content"

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

2- Use WP_Query();

```
<php $my_query = new WP_Query("category_name=destaques");
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

   "content"

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

3: Use query_posts();

```
<?php query_posts( 'category_name=destaques' );
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

   "content"

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Which you choose and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The optimal choice is get_posts();**

Here is the reasoning from the [Wordpress Function Reference for query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> The query_posts() function is intended
>   to be used to modify the main page
>   loop only. It is not intended as a
>   means to create secondary loops on the
>   page. If you want to create separate
>   Loops outside of the main one, you
>   should use get_posts() instead. Use of
>   query_posts() on loops other than the
>   main one can result in your main loop
>   becoming incorrect and possibly
>   displaying things that you were not
>   expecting.
>
> The query_posts() function overrides
>   and replaces the main query for the
>   page. To save your sanity, do not use
>   it for any other purpose.
>
> The query_posts() function creates a
>   new WP_Query object and assign it to
>   global wp_query variable. The
>   get_posts() function creates a new
>   WP_Query object without overriding
>   anything in the global area.

Comment: Right. But I still wonder about the difference between using get_posts and WP_Query.

Comment: get_posts() creates a new wp_query, without overriding the global variables....This may provide some additional information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query

Comment: Hi Kory, thanks for your tip, i found that for pagination i can only get working with query_posts(); but only if i declare the global variable $wp_query. I will test with get_posts() to see if i get the same result, thanks again.

Comment: Awesome, no problem. Interested to hear if it worked out as you wanted it to?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about others but my choice is most often or not

```
<?php 
query_posts('showposts=1&cat=-48'); // our custom query
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  // Start the loop
    $img = get_post_meta($post->ID, "postimage", $single = true);//any custom fields?
?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
<?php
endwhile; endif;// End the Loop and Check for Posts
wp_reset_query(); // Reset the loop
?>
<div>stuff</div>
<?php 
query_posts('showposts=5&cat=5'); // our custom query
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  // Start the loop
    $img = get_post_meta($post->ID, "postimage", $single = true);//any custom fields?
?>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    etc..etc..
<?php
endwhile; endif;// End the Loop and Check for Posts
wp_reset_query(); // Reset the loop
?>
```

this proves to work fine for my needs...

Comment: Hi Marty, sorry for the delay, i also prefer this approach, but i am getting some trouble with pagination, do you have problems with that too? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use number 3. It's easier to read and understand.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I realize that in hindsight.